# Selective deep clone

Tags: javascript, json, nested, clone, deep-copy

**Question**

We are trying to clone an object, while deep cloning some nested fields, shallow cloning others and excluding even others entirely.

E.g.

```js
const clone = (obj, fields) => { /* ... */ };

const data = { a: {}, b: {}, c: {} };
const cloned = clone(data, ['b', '!c']);

console.log(cloned);
// => { a: {}, b: {} }
console.log(cloned.a !== data.a);
// => true
console.log(cloned.b === data.b);
// => true
```

How would we best do this in javascript? Is there a library that can already do this?

---

**Answer**

Unfortunately I can't answer this question anymore since it has been closed, so I'm answering it here. I couldn't find a library doing this or something similar, so I've impemented it myself in [object-lib](https://github.com/blackflux/object-lib).

```js
const { clone } = require('object-lib');

/* ... code from above ... */
```

Comment: how would you specify what you want to clone

Comment: You would exclude what you didn't want to clone. In the example it would be `b.y` and `c[0]`

Comment: so like as strings in the function arguments?

Comment: Something like `clone(data, ['**', '!b.y', '!c[0]'])` or `clone(data, ['b.y', 'c[0]'])`

Comment: Use any clone solution and use those expressions to filter? Did you try anything? There are several Q&A on cloning and even more on filtering.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the reply! I was hoping to find an existing library. I've now implemented this in object-lib: https://github.com/blackflux/object-lib

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question, but I wouldn't count on it being reopened. You can also instead post your answer as an answer in the duplicate question (which is still open), probably best to do so there.

Comment: @costaparas Thank you! That question is a bit different since it doesn't deal with shallow cloning. I'm afraid that if I answered there, the answer would get down voted as not really answering the question. I'm quite happy with my question + answer here. Just a bit unfortunate that it was closed as duplicate